# Redirect to a page after an Ajax call where URL is determined in Spring controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, jsp, redirect

On my JSP page, I am making an Ajax post to my Spring controller.  I use the data I am posting to determine where I should make a redirect call to.  So my code would look like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/postFromJSP" method={RequestMethod.POST})
public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response,
                         @RequestBody MyAjaxData data) {

    RestResponse restResponse = determineRedirect(data);

    if (restResponse.getStatusCode()==302) {
       //redirect to URL from response
       Cookie cookie = generateCookie(restResponse.getJson());
       url = restResponse.getJson.getURL();
       response.addCookie(cookie);
       response.sendRedirect(url);
     }
  }
```

However, from my JSP page, when I examine the network traffic, I see a `307` response to my redirect request to the specified URL, and the view doesn't change from my JSP.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to add in a success function in my Ajax to make the redirect?

Answer (score 2):

Change Spring Controller like this.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/postFromJSP" method={RequestMethod.POST})
 public RestResponse sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
                     HttpServletResponse response,
                     @RequestBody MyAjaxData data) {

RestResponse restResponse = determineRedirect(data);

return restResponse ;
```

}

Handle the response inside the callback function in .js

Comment: I'll give that a try!